# Grabbing images or searching for images in home_timeline using Rails Twitter gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twitter

I'm using Twitter gem with Rails 3.0 and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to locate images within home_timeline. I know that if an image is posted with a tweet, it has a link but I'm not sure where to start for searching it. Nothing I know worked so far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `client.home_timeline` method which I assume you are using, returns an array of Tweet objects. Then just use the Ruby array method `delete_if` to remove all tweets that don't have images (I assume `tweet.media` will be nil if no image, but I'm not positive). The remaining tweets in the array will all have images accessible through the `tweet.media` instance method. The code would like this. 
`client.home_timeline.delete_if {|tweet| tweet.media.nil?}`